# cloning HTML and render it with custom text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of tb-team-name a when clicking `.tb-delete-team a` but for some reason it renders like

> "Are you sure you want to delete `[object Object]`?"

When I do

`$('.hutdb-modal-body').html(nameOutput);`

it shows the link as it should do. What am I doing wrong? (I'm not very good at jQuery)

**HTML**

```
 <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td width="80%;" class="row-label tb-team-name bold"><a href="/17/builder/12037">Goon Squad</a></td>
    <td class="tb-synergy">3</td>
    <td class="tb-team-overall">86.05</td>
    <td class="tb-delete-team"><a class="table-button" href="/s/builder/del/12037"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.tb-delete-team a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var addressValue = $(this).attr('href');
    var nameValue    = $(this).parent('#my_teams_wrapper table tbody tr td').parent('#my_teams_wrapper table tbody tr').children('.tb-team-name').children('a');
    var nameOutput   = nameValue.clone().val('.tb-team-name');

    $(this).each(function () {
        $('.hutdb-overlay').show();
        $('.hutdb-modal').fadeIn();

        $('.hutdb-modal-body').html('Are you sure you want to delete ' + nameOutput + '?');

        $('.hutdb-modal-button-group').html( '<a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a><a class="confirm" href="'+addressValue+'"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</a>' );
        $('.hutdb-modal-button-group .cancel').click(function() {
            $('.hutdb-modal').hide();
            $('.hutdb-overlay').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: because it is a jQuery object....

Comment: lol ok, I'm a newbie. I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using below for nameValue:

```
var nameValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tb-team-name').text();
```

`closest` matches and returns the first parent selector in the DOM. See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

The above code first traverse up in the DOM till it meets the first `tr` (its parent) and then traverse down into the matched `tr` and finds `.tb-team-name` and retrieves its value (or the text of the `<a>` tag).

You may not need `nameOutput` after that.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
var nameOutput = nameValue.clone().val('.tb-team-name');
```

should probably be

```
var nameOutput = nameValue.clone().val();
```

Though I am curious why you are cloning the initial element. Overall I think you are trying too hard to traverse the DOM when a judicious use of an ID or class would make this a trivial 4 line task.

Comment: Ok but now it renders blank instead? I 100% agree that my code is very bad.

Comment: Looks like it should be .val($('.tb-team-name').val());